# How to update geolocations without imposing to much load on server

Tags: android, geolocation, server-side, client-side, polling

I have a set of entities with GPS trackers on them. They will make connections to my server using sockets and update their location.
I have an android application which is used by many customers and they show position of entities on map and. It is required to update position of entities on map.

How can I receive updated location of entities on each android client such that it have minimum load on my server (consider large number of android clients)?
I think periodic polling in a large number will convert to something like a DDOS attack and cannot be scaled.

What is an alternative solution for my problem?

Comment: Push notifications?

Comment: @greenapps They are not gauranteed to deliver and their delay may vary too much

Comment: [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) could work perhaps, but I don't have much more to say about it myself.